# Generate JSON with jackson-asl - empty stream

Tags: java, json, jackson

Due to several constraints (of avoiding at all costs to change the pom), I am trying to generate JSON with an old jackson-core-asl-1.0.0.jar library. Here is the code I wrote:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonEncoding;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonFactory;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerator;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

public class JacksonTest {

    private void mapToJsonAndOutput(OutputStream out, Map<String, String> data) throws IOException {
        JsonFactory f = new JsonFactory();
        JsonGenerator g = f.createJsonGenerator(out, JsonEncoding.UTF8);
        g.writeStartObject();
        for (Entry<String, String> e : data.entrySet()) {
            g.writeStringField(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
        }
        g.writeEndObject();
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() throws IOException {
        String expectedJson = "{\"type\":\"dog\",\"name\":\"Spike\"}";
        Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
        data.put("type", "dog");
        data.put("name", "Spike");
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        mapToJsonAndOutput(baos, data);
        String result = new String(baos.toByteArray());
        Assert.assertNotNull(result);
        Assert.assertTrue(result.length() > 0);
    }
}
```

I think I followed [the doc](http://docs.codehaus.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=227053544) (even if what I need is not exactly the same as what they made), but the last Assert fails (String is empty). Tried to manually flush and close the stream but nothing changes. Any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not closing `JsonGenerator`: contents will remain buffered in intermediate buffer. Call to `JsonParser.flush()` would also work, but there are other good reasons to properly close the generator (for performance, some of underlying data structs are recycled).